# How to remove bar from QMainWindow

Tags: qt, toolbar, statusbar

I'm trying to delete this bar, butI can't get rid of it (it's locate just under the toolbar):

[image]

What is the name of that bar,how can I access it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you added that tool bar you probably have a pointer to it? If yes, you can simply call:

```
removeToolBar(toolbar);
```

in your `QMainWindow` class. Otherwise you can remove all tool bars from the main window as:

```
QList<QToolBar *> allToolBars = mainWindow->findChildren<QToolBar *>();
foreach(QToolBar *tb, allToolBars) {
    // This does not delete the tool bar.
    mainWindow->removeToolBar(tb);
}
```

Comment: I did not add that toolbar, it comes with each QMainWindow by default.

Comment: @xpg94, really? I don't see a tool bar when create an instance of QMainWindow.

Comment: You missunderstood me. I'm not talking about the toolbar, I'm talking about the other "bar", the thing which I tried to show on the image I uploaded with my question.

Comment: @xpg94 What you showed is a toolbar (just below the menu bar). You can take a look at https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qmainwindow.html#removeToolBar to see options to remove it. If you are creating your window in the Qt Designer, check http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/designer-creating-mainwindows.html to see how to remove the toolbar.

Comment: You are right. It seems that I missunderstood you in the end. Problem is solved,thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

What you are calling the `toolbar` is actually the menu bar and what you are calling the `other bar` is actually an emtpy toolbar.

The most likely reason you have an empty toolbar is because you created your window using QtDesigner. If you choose a `QMainWindow` as your starting point, it automatically adds an empty menubar and an empty toolbar to the window. If you don't want the toolbar, find it in the Object Inspector on the right-hand side, right-click and select `Remove Toolbar 'mainToolbar'` (or whatever other name is the default).

Answer (score 2):

Below adds a little to @RobbieE's answer.

When creating a `QMainWindow` form, it creates `mainToolBar` for the user.

If you right click on it and select `Remove Toolbar 'mainToolBar'` it will be gone.

Or in code in the top of your constructor:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

delete ui->mainToolBar; // add this line
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The name of your menu bar may vary. My default mine was menubar, so: delete ui->menubar;