# Qt: How get rid of grey bar at the top of the window (below the title bar)?

Tags: macos, qt, qwidget

[image: Window with weird grey bar]

I'm trying to make a simple Qt application, but after creating one according to the example at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html, I get a weird grey bar at the top of the window, right under the title bar that I do not want.

Can anyone tell me what this grey bar is called so I can find documentation on it, and maybe even tell me how to remove it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove bar from QMainWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416781/how-to-remove-bar-from-qmainwindow)

Comment: If it's draggable, it's most likely an empty toolbar

Comment: @RobbieE It's not draggable, but on your mention of tool bars I did `setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true)` and that that removed the separator between that area and the window title bar. You were spot-on and it is a weird fake Qt version of a toolbar, which with that information I was able to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably a menu bar without any menus on it. If you're using Qt Designer, you can right-click on it and select "Remove Menu Bar". If you want to remove it in code, I believe you should call `QMainWindow::setMenuBar (0)`.

More likely, you'll want to add menu items to it rather than remove it, but that depends on what you want to do with your application.

Comment: I have a menu bar, but that already shows at the top of the screen (as it should on macOS). If I setMenuBar(nullptr), it just completely removes those menus as well (though the grey bar stays), so I don't think it's a menu bar. For good measure I tried setMenuWidget(nullptr), but that didn't help either.

Comment: Ah...I didn't catch that it was Mac. Then it's probably a toolbar. You can either remove it in Designer by right-clicking, or you can remove it programmatically with QMainWindow::removeToolBar.